# Require a method or library that convert word to vector directly

Tags: machine-learning

I want to train my model with words and their label so do anyone have a method in which i will pass a word and it will return vector, that will be great help thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! And good luck with your problem. You'll have to give more details, though, for us to help you. For instance, what language and tools are you working with?

Comment: I am using python and i am trying to classify some word in 4 parts as i have word i cant train it directly so can u suggest any method which convert my words or string to any array of numbers?

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction